# Bulk insert based on condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I am importing data into SQL Server table using bulk insert.

```
BULK INSERT MySampleDB.dbo.Sample 
FROM ''' + @location + '''    
WITH 
    (
     FIRSTROW = 2,    
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ''","'',      
     ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',     
     TABLOCK    
    )
```

I need to do check condition like if the column value whether it is an integer. If it is not an integer then I need to skip that entire record from inserting.

Answer (score 0):

use case when script to understand its an integer or not.

look [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In my thought, you can not do this in the bulk insert but you can  this help of the following the steps in the below.

**Step-1 :** First of all, you can add a varchar data type column to your table so that you can map CSV column to this column.

**Step-2 :** You can update the int column through the **TRY_CONVERT** function

```
   CREATE TABLE Bulk_InsertTable
    (ColImport VARCHAR(100) , ColINT INT)  
    GO
 CREATE VIEW Viev_Bulk_InsertTable
    AS SELECT ColImportVarchar
       FROM Bulk_InsertTable
    GO
    BULK INSERT Viev_Bulk_InsertTable FROM 'C:\Test.csv' 
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
    TABLOCK
    )

    UPDATE Bulk_InsertTable
      SET ColINT = TRY_CONVERT(INT, ColImport);


    +--------------+-----------+
    |  ColImport   |  ColINT   |
    +--------------+-----------+
    | 669165933    | 669165933 |
    | 871543967AAA | NULL      |
    | 871543967AAA | NULL      |
    | 514321792    | 514321792 |
    | 115456712    | 115456712 |
    +--------------+-----------+
```